# Add a label to each option menu in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a widget in which there are many different option menu. I need to add to each option menu the appropriate label to the left of it.

My code looks like this:

```
from tkinter import*

class MyOptionMenu(OptionMenu):
    def __init__(self, master, status, *options):
        self.var = StringVar(master)
        self.var.set(status)
        OptionMenu.__init__(self, master, self.var, *options)
        self.config(font=('calibri',(8)),bg='white',width=20)
        self['menu'].config(font=('calibri',(8)),bg='white')


root = Tk()
optionList1 = items1
optionList2 = items2
optionList3 = items3
optionList4 = items4
optionList5 = items5
lab1 = Label(root, text="condition №1", font="Arial 8", anchor='w')
mymenu1 = MyOptionMenu(root, '-', *optionList1)
lab2 = Label(root, text="condition №2", font="Arial 8", anchor='w')
mymenu2 = MyOptionMenu(root, '-', *optionList2)
lab3 = Label(root, text="condition №3", font="Arial 8", anchor='w')
mymenu3 = MyOptionMenu(root, '-', *optionList3)
lab4 = Label(root, text="condition №4", font="Arial 8", anchor='w')
mymenu4 = MyOptionMenu(root, '-', *optionList4)
lab = Label(root, text="Enter the date", font="Arial 8", anchor='w')
ent1 = Entry(root,width=20,bd=3)
lab5 = Label(root, text="condition №5", font="Arial 8", anchor='w')
mymenu5 = MyOptionMenu(root, '-', *optionList5)
lab1.pack(side="top",fill = "x")
mymenu1.pack(side="top",fill = "y")
lab2.pack(side="top",fill = "x")
mymenu2.pack(side="top",fill = "y")
lab3.pack(side="top", fill="x")
mymenu3.pack(side="top", fill="y")
lab4.pack(side="top", fill="x")
mymenu4.pack(side="top", fill = "y")
lab.pack(side="top", fill="x")
ent1.pack(side="top", fill="y")
lab5.pack(side="top", fill="x")
mymenu5.pack(side="top", fill = "y")

def save_selected_values(): 
    global values1
    values1 = [mymenu1.var.get(), mymenu2.var.get(), mymenu3.var.get(), mymenu4.var.get(), ent1.get(), mymenu5.var.get()]
    print(values1)

button = Button(root, text="OK", command=save_selected_values)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: The result looks like this]

But I need each label to be at the appropriate line with a drop-down list

In the Excel it looks like this:

[image]

Where each row in column B is a drop-down list.

I understand that `fill = "x"` fills the whole line, but when I try to change it, it looks even worse.

I would be grateful for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your given Excel example, I would use the [`grid` geometry manager](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_grid.htm) for your purpose, which places items in a grid layout. With it you can specify row and column. I also would store all the labels and dropdowns in a list for easier access. Then you can use:

```
for index, (lab, mymenu) in enumerate(zip(labels, mymenus)):
    lab.grid(row=index, column=0)
    mymenu.grid(row=index, column=1)
```

Comment: Tried to correct grammar. If my edit changed what you tried to say, feel free to rollback.

Comment: @Lafexlos It does change my original intention what I wanted to say, but your version sounds better so im not rolling it back. Originally I wanted to say that the Asker used a grid layout in the excel Example, so I would use the same in tkinter.